# Unable to get location on Android

Tags: android, google-api

I want to get the location of the device at app startup.

I have been looking through the docs, trying to figure out what goes wrong, but I can't seem to find it. onLocationChanged is never called.

```
private void getLocation() {
    // Connected to Google API

    // Create location request with minimum interval of a minute, and normal of an hour
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 60);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60 * 60);

    // Request permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"}, MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION_CODE);
        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION_CODE: {
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
            else {
                TextView loading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.connecting_text);
                loading.setText("Please enable Location under Settings > Apps > Beet > Permissions.");
                loading.setTextSize(20);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    System.out.println("GETLOCATION1 ________________");
    mLastLocation = location;
    System.out.println(location.getLatitude() + " - " + location.getLongitude() + " ________________");
}
```

Comment: try to debug your code , `onRequestPermissionsResult` is getting called or not and check is permission is getting granted

Comment: The end of 'getLocation' is reached.

Comment: try to debug all points in my above comment , if `onRequestPermissionsResult` isn't get called mean something wrong with your permission code but you have to narrow down the issue like it's about permission or location and try to look at logcat too

Comment: Can't it be that ' if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)' evaluates as true? Seeing as  the function reaches the end. The app is already given the required permissions on the emulator.

Comment: you have to mimic the location on emulator , see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247350/emulators-location-simulation-not-working and look for similar information

Answer (score 0):

Try getting permission like this: it works in my case

```
if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"}, MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION_CODE);
        }

private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  Call_location_updates();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.gps_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Also create your LocationRequest object like this:

```
private final int INTERVAL = 5000;
private final int FAST_INTERVAL = 1000;

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

}



 public void Call_location_updates(){
         Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //do what u want with location
    }
```