# Cannot detect location on emulator, Android Studios

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, google-location-services

I have forked an Android application on Github (https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/BasicLocation) which demonstrates use of Google Play services Location API to get the last known location for a device.

However, when I try and run the application, I receive a Toast message that states "No location detected. Make sure location is enabled on the device."

[image]

I have added the following permissions to the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In addition, the Extended controls of the emulator reads my current lat/long coordinates

[image]

I was wondering how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Run the google map app and give it all the permissions and after the map show start your app.
check this one for more inf.
[Emulator's Location simulation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247350/emulators-location-simulation-not-working)