# Emulator's Location simulation Showing white blank screen

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

My Emulator's Location simulation Shows a white blank screen as shown [Location Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EZXi.png)
I tried everything in here [emulators-location-simulation-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247350/emulators-location-simulation-not-working)
and Still not Working

I expect to find a solution to this case

Answer (score 0):

update your android emulator through settings (cog icon in the top right) -> sdk manager -> sdk tools tab -> android emulator (just recheck the box to make it a checkmark then proceed to update using the apply button)

before updating make sure your virtual device is shut down and that your emulator is closed, otherwise updating will fail

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552795/23151879