# Google Maps not loading on Extended Controls Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-virtual-device

Is anybody else facing this same issue I am trying to set route on extended controls but I am getting a blank map, I have updated & reinstalled Android Studio and AVD but still I am facing this issue which is frustrating.

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVL43.png)

I am expecting to see a Google Map on extended controls of the Android Studio Emulator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the fix for anyone facing this issue go to Android Studio > SDK Manager > SDK Tools then if there is a written update available select that and update it.

Below is this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of SDK Tools]

Comment: Glad it did !